# Regex find ( xx OR xx )

Tags: regex

To split up some text I am trying to make a regex that covers the following:
A part of text that starts with `(` untill the first `)` and where OR is in between the match.

Example input 1:

```
(Test OR test2) some more text
```

Wanted match 1:

```
(Test OR test2)
```

---

Example input 2:

```
(Test OR test2 OR test3) some more text (TEST1 OR test2)
```

Wanted match 2:

```
(Test OR test2 OR test 3)
```

---

If there is no OR in the text for example

```
"(Test AND test2 AND test3) some more text"
```

Then I do not want to match.

I was able to make a regex for getting text withing ():

`(\([^)]+\))`

How should I update it for the above user case?

Comment: Maybe `\([^()]*\bOR\b[^()]*\)`?

Comment: You can use this: `\((?=[^)]*OR)[^)]+\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\([^()]*\bOR\b[^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uatz7P/1)

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\bOR\b` - a whole word `OR`
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.